# Reset mysql root password on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Is there a simple way of setting the mysql root password on Ubuntu if I have root access and closing the database shortly is not an issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not have many tables this should run in 10 seconds.

```
pass=MyNewPass
echo "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$pass';" > mysqlinit
sudo chown mysql:mysql mysqlinit
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --init-file=`pwd`/mysqlinit &
sleep 2
sudo killall mysqld
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
sudo rm mysqlinit
sql mysql://root:$pass@/mysql
```

Comment: i vote up. i never has seen this way, but its a very good idea. thank

Comment: @Hugo Please post the best way as an answer so we can learn what is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

**Open your terminal**

```
`sudo mysql -u root
use mysql;
SELECT user, plugin FROM user;
UPDATE user SET plugin = "mysql_native_password" WHERE user = "root" ;
exit
service mysql restart`
```

Comment: Add some description.